# Get path of shell script that calls a C program from the C program

Tags: c

I have a shell script that calls a C program. Can we get the path of this shell script in the C program being called by it?

Comment: In a simple way - No. If you still intend to do it in a hackish non portable way, you can call `ps` from the C program and look for the name of the process where the process id == your parent id. Assuming this is Linux. There has to be something similar for Windows

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps say why you think you need to do that and someone may have a better solution to achieve what you really need to do.

Comment: You could always pass the path as one of the arguments to main. However, I agree with kaylum.